# How to handle dependencies in Web APIs

Tags: web-api

I'm struggling with a decision about how to design a web-API where I create new "things".
We roughly follow the API guidelines of Zalando, which do provide a nice starting point for web-APIs (https://opensource.zalando.com/restful-api-guidelines/). But there's no guidance on how to handle creating new resources, which might have dependencies.

To provide a simple example, I have a beloved automotive example.

Assume the following API:

`GET /vehicle` - will get a list of vehicles
`POST /vehicle` - will create a new vehicle

The vehicle might look something like this

```cs
class Vehicle {
  VehicleType Type { get; set; }

}

enum VehicleType { // This enum is an example - it might as well be some complex type.
  eCar,
  Car,
  Truck
}
```

Now for the Post, I need to know about valid VehicleTypes.

Would I rather do:
`GET /vehicle-type` or
`GET /vehicle/types` or
`GET /vehicle/dependencies/types` or
`GET /new-vehicle` and include the dependencies?

Which approach is "well-known"? Are there other well known approaches?

Comment: Vehicle types don't depend on Vehicle (it's just the opposite) so `/vehicle-types` seems reasonable to me.

Comment: If the vehicle types are unlikely to change and there are only some valid values, I prefer putting the list of valid values to the API documentation to creating a separated endpoint.

Comment: @HieuLe that leads to hardcode values on the client-side. New values might force you to deploy new versions of the client and this is important if we were speaking about mobile apps.

Comment: I agree. That is the reason I'll only hardcode these value if they are unlikely to change. In this use case, I think the list of supported vehicle types won't change frequently.

Answer (score 4):

I think that types are not a dependency of Vehicle in this scenario. A vehicle type still exists without a vehicle but presumably, a vehicle cannot exist without a type?

```
GET /vehicle-type HTTP/1.1
```

Would be fine in my opinion.

Comment: Yes - the vehicle depends on the type - it's neccessary.  
So - essentially you'd go for a resource for every dependency of such an type or could you think of exceptions?

Comment: Look at these endpoints as lookups. If you want clients to get up-to-date values of `vehicle-types` then you have to provide an endpoint. Once on the client-side, you may cache the list of `vehicle-types` for a while (minutes, hours) or during the whole session.

Comment: ==@Laiv - cache the response! You shouldn't need to check for new values more often than once a day - surely clients can wait that long. Maybe even once a week.

Comment: Caches are evil. The shorter-living they are the better. If we were speaking about web apps, we could use the HTTP cache headers too.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to do a get at all.

The guidelines you quote require that you publish a schema for all your objects. This would include the enum eg (example from https://swagger.io/specification/#schemaObject):

```
"huntingSkill": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "The measured skill for hunting",
            "default": "lazy",
            "enum": [
              "clueless",
              "lazy",
              "adventurous",
              "aggressive"
            ]
          }
```

So the enum will be encoded into the client along with the definition of Vehicle

Comment: Heh - you're right.
The example I choose is somewhat short, it might not be an enum, but a pseudo enum like a group to be choosen from or any other dependency as well. So you are correct for REAL enums :)

Comment: surely other things are covered by their own resource?

Comment: That might or might not be. And I wanted to have input, how people handle dependencies, to be able to distill a best-practice.

Comment: Now just decide whether to deploy Swagger's endpoints on production is convenient or not and if you want to lock your solution to it.